# GridView RowUpdating not working in second page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I am using the following code to update values in a gridview during `OnUpdating` command,

```
protected void grid_view_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grid_view.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl("flatnumber")).Text);
    string type = ((DropDownList)row.Cells[4].FindControl("flattype")).Text;
    int max = Convert.ToInt32(((DropDownList)row.Cells[5].FindControl("flatvacancy")).Text);
    string flatID = ((Label)row.Cells[0].FindControl("flatid")).Text;
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Table"];
    DataRow[] datarow = dt.Select("ID='" + flatID + "'");
    dt.Rows[e.RowIndex].BeginEdit();
    dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Number"] = number;
    dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Type"] = type;
    dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Vacancy"] = max;
    dt.Rows[e.RowIndex].EndEdit();
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    ViewState["Table"] = dt;
    grid_view.EditIndex = -1;
    grid_view.DataSource = dt;
    grid_view.DataBind();
}
```

This code works fine in the first page of grid view, but when I try to edit the 2nd page it does not work. When I click on edit button the corresponding row edit template is loading. When I click save instead of saving to second page the first page row gets modified. Example if i click edit in 2nd row of 2nd page and after i click update, the 3nd row of 1st page is modified with the new value and not the 2nd row of 2nd page.

My RowEditing and CancelEditing codes are below,

```
protected void grid_view_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grid_view.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Table"];
    grid_view.DataSource = dt;
    grid_view.DataBind();
}

protected void grid_view_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    grid_view.EditIndex = -1;
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Table"];
    grid_view.DataSource = dt;
    grid_view.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the updated values using just `e.RowIndex` but to make changes in Datatable you have to add the product of `grid_view.PageIndex` and `grid_view.PageSize` to `e.RowIndex` to make the changes in the actual row.

```
protected void grid_view_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grid_view.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl("flatnumber")).Text);
    string type = ((DropDownList)row.Cells[4].FindControl("flattype")).Text;
    int max = Convert.ToInt32(((DropDownList)row.Cells[5].FindControl("flatvacancy")).Text);
    string flatID = ((Label)row.Cells[0].FindControl("flatid")).Text;
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Table"];
    int row1=e.RowIndex+(grid_view.PageIndex*grid_view.PageSize)
    dt.Rows[row1].BeginEdit();
    dt.Rows[row1]["Number"] = number;
    dt.Rows[row1]["Type"] = type;
    dt.Rows[row1]["Vacancy"] = max;
    dt.Rows[row1].EndEdit();
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    ViewState["Table"] = dt;
    grid_view.EditIndex = -1;
    grid_view.DataSource = dt;
    grid_view.DataBind();
}
```